# How to make HashWithIndifferentAccess as default for params in Sinatra controllers?

Tags: ruby, hashmap, sinatra, rack

Is it possible to make HashWithIndifferentAccess as default for params in Sinatra controllers like Rails, so that i can use symbols instead of strings in controllers?

```
post '/books' do
  Book.create(title: params[:book][:title])
end
```

instead of

```
post '/books' do
  Book.create(title: params['book']['title'])
end
```

Comment: huh? Either way should work in Sinatra.

Comment: thats true, either way would work. although the params returns just a Hash object, but its constructed with a key handling block which converts the key to string. you can see how this works here at https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb line 929. I suppose they dont want to depend on Active support for this tiny bit.

Comment: a little of topic... but i hate HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: @irfn if you click the line number Github gives you a link to that line https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L929

Comment: @iain thanks for that info, didnt know that Github can do that.